# Finding id of a specific page

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I want to extract event information from a certain webpage. But I get only a little part of content not the entire content. Only if I click the "read more" link or clicking on that specific link I get the entire data. So I noticed that the id in the url is only changing but I don't know how to extract the id from url. If I specify a place as i/p and pass its id in the program then it would be more easy. How can I be able to access the id?

Comment: So basically you want to parse the url to get the query parameters, right? How about using the `getQuery` method of the `URL` class in java?

Comment: but it only helps to access only url details of one page. How should I access each and every sublinks

Comment: Wouldn't jsoup allow you to parse the html to obtain all links from the page? Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do in more detail, perhaps with an example?

Comment: About link visiting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780291/using-jsoup-how-can-i-fetch-each-and-every-information-resides-in-each-link/13787508#13787508

Comment: @Harry take a look at this site http://www.kerala.com/keralaevents/index.php...I want to extract only events, exhibitions and festivals of each place not the other contents..How can I?

Comment: @Harry chk that link .if I click on that "More" link then only I will be able to get the entire data.Is there any way to extract all info related to events and exhibitions

Answer (score 0):

To get the complete details of each event, you will have to parse [this](http://www.kerala.com/keralaevents/events.php) link to get each event. From each such node, you will need to find the link with class `more` and follow that link. From the new page you get, you will need to parse the html to get the event details text.

(You can get these class names, etc. by viewing the html of the page or using the web inspector in your browser)

The basic logic will be something like:

```
 root = fetch page with url given above
 L = list of nodes with class newsbrdr on root
 for each node N in L:
      a_node = child of N with class 'more'
      p = fetch page at a_node's href
      extract the paragraph text from element on p with class 'newsdesc'
```